# EdgeNgramField min and max letters in django haystack

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

Is there a way to restrict the size of the edge ngrams in django haystack indexing? For example, I create the ngram as follows:

```
#search_indexes.py
content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')
```

But I don't want to create 2 letter ngrams, I actually want to set the min at 4 or 5.

As background, I am using django-haystack/elasticsearch, with bonsai on heroku.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is override the search mapping in Haystack's ElasticSearch backend.

In brief: extend the ElasticSearch backend and either replace directly or by a `settings.py` import a new schema mapping.

```
from django.conf import settings
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import (ElasticsearchSearchBackend,
    ElasticsearchSearchEngine)

class MyElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(ConfigurableElasticBackend, self).__init__(
                                connection_alias, **connection_options)
        MY_SETTINGS = {
            'settings': {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "ngram_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                            "filter": ["haystack_ngram"]
                        },
                        "edgengram_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                            "filter": ["haystack_edgengram"]
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                            "type": "nGram",
                            "min_gram": 3,
                            "max_gram": 15,
                        },
                        "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                            "type": "edgeNGram",
                            "min_gram": 2,
                            "max_gram": 15,
                            "side": "front"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "haystack_ngram": {
                            "type": "nGram",
                            "min_gram": 3,
                            "max_gram": 15
                        },
                        "haystack_edgengram": {
                            "type": "edgeNGram",
                            "min_gram": 5,
                            "max_gram": 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        setattr(self, 'DEFAULT_SETTINGS', MY_SETTINGS)


class ConfigurableElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
    backend = MyElasticBackend
```

For a fuller explanation see my [write up about extending the ElasticSearch backend](http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/) to customize the search mapping.

Answer (score -1):

Its actually quite simple. Just create a folder called `search_configuration` inside your template directory. Then, create a file `solr.xml` and paste the contents of the solr.xml file [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/tree/master/haystack/templates/search_configuration) into that file. Finally, edit the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` to set the minGramSize as appropriate.